# Set variables depending on Gitlab rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have 2 environments (development, production). Per default we deploy to production but if the branch name or the commit message start with ***dev*** we deploy to development environment.

I create variables (***app_url*** and ***app_url_dev***) via gitlab GUI : (Project => Settings => CI/CD => Variables)

I use gitlab rule to change the ***app_url*** variable of deployement. The script ***deploy.py*** (and many other scripts) are using ***app_url*** variable.

The gitlab-ci code is:

```
Tags:
  stage: Deploy code
  rules:
  #    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^dev/
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^dev/
        variables:
          app_url: $app_url_dev
  script:
  - Python deploy.py
```

The problem is that i never get the value of app_url_dev in app_url. I tried other combinaison but i always get the production url and not the dev one:

```
app_url: ${app_url_dev}
app_url: app_url_dev
```

But i get always the ***app_url*** and not the ***app_url_dev***.
Anyone can help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable expansion made in `rules:variables:` section. You can only set a simple text value for a variable.

For an `app_url`, you may consider using the `environment:url:` [section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-ciyml-file), which is where variable expansion works. But you can't use it inside of `rules:`.

Or have some conditional logic in the `script:` section.

Comment: Not sure if something has changed since this answer, but this is no longer true. I have tested this and you can definitely use another variable inside a `rules:variable` var

Answer (score 8):

As Brennan said in a comment above, something might have changed as variable expansion works in the `rules:variables` block now.

Here's what's working for me:

```
variables:
  DEPLOY_KEY: "$DEPLOY_KEY_DEV" # global fallback

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - bash ./deploy.sh
  rules:
    - if: $DEPLOY_ENV == "production" # can use trigger variables for evaluation
      variables:
        DEPLOY_KEY: "$DEPLOY_KEY_PROD" # can expand project variables into other variables
    - if: $DEPLOY_ENV == "staging"
      variables:
        DEPLOY_KEY: "$DEPLOY_KEY_STAGING"
```

Comment: What GitLab release & tier are you guys using? I'm attempting to do something very similar to the OP, out of sheer coincidence, and I'm not seeing variable expansion in rules:variables. I have a 'variables' block in one of my rules, with a PARAMETER_A variable whose value I set as $SOME_ENV_PARAMETER_A, and rather than getting the expected value of the $SOME_ENV_PARAMETER_A variable when the pipeline is assembled, I instead get the string literal  '$SOME_ENV_PARAMETER_A' value, which needless to say foils my plans. I'm using GitLab 15.11.3-ce. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'm using `16.1.0` and Enterprise, but I had this implemented already on `15.x.x`. It's hard to say what the issue is without seeing code, but [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-cicd-variables-in-job-scripts) on GitLab shows that with Bash (and similar) shells, you access with double-quotes; in PowerShell, you shouldn't use any quotes. If that's not the case, [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#prevent-cicd-variable-expansion) mentions how you can disable variable expansion for specific variables - maybe that's the issue? Good luck!

Comment: Maybe the confusion here is that you cannot use variables declared in the job itself?